# R: Convert a difftime matrix into an integer matrix to divide

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to divide two matrices, but one of them is a matrix of datediff (number of days between a vector of dates) and I get an error of:  "second arg of / cannot be a difftime object.  I've tried converting using as.integer(), or as.matrix(as.integer()) but those result in a vector.

reprex:

```
numerator <- matrix(1:49, nrow = 7, ncol = 7)
d <- seq(as.Date("2021-05-04"), as.Date("2021-06-15"), by = "week")
divisor <- outer(d, d, FUN = '-' )
output <- numerator/divisor
```

```
> output <- numerator/divisor
Error in `/.difftime`(numerator, divisor) : 
  second argument of / cannot be a "difftime" object
```

How do I do the element-wise division of these two matrices?

Comment: Does this give you what you want? `output <- numerator/as.numeric(divisor)`

Comment: ha, yes that did the trick, and I'm embarrassed to say that I didn't realize that.  Thanks! If you want to submit as a reply I will mark as answered.